# What is the purpose of user interface module in css3?

Tags: css

I am trying to gain knowledge of CSS3 so I know user interface module, it provides a bunch of properties in that has resize property, but I dont know why it has resize property that allow user to change size of elements.In addition to that I have no idea of what is purpose of user interface module is used for.
so I hope someone can answer this to me.
very thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 3 (CSS3 UI)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3)* by Tantek Çelik and Florian Rivoal (editors), W3C candidate recommendation of 2 March 2017, has the following to say:

> The purpose of this specification is to achieve the following objectives: extend the user interface features in CSS2.1; provide additional CSS mechanisms to augment or replace other dynamic presentation related features in HTML; introduce directional navigation properties to assist in the construction of user interfaces which make use of a directional navigation model.

Please note that a styling property does not become instantly available in all browsers just because the W3C published a candidate recommendation. You should check that you can actually use the properties described in the document. [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/) comes to mind.

As far as I can tell the specification provides some nice tools for styling interactive HTML documents, such as web-based applications. For example, it allows drawing outlines around objects, modifying the shape of the mouse cursor and other such goodies. Whether you want to use them or not, and indeed whether you *can* use them or not depends on your design and your target audience.

As to "why it has resize property": because it exists in some browsers. In this case the W3C just documents and standardizes an already existing technology.